# CanvasJS docs show weird datapoints on the x-axis

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, datetime, canvasjs

So, I've been looking at the docs here:
https://canvasjs.com/php-charts/multi-series-area-chart/

It shows the datapoints array like this:

```
array("x" => 1451586600000, "y" => 96.709),
array("x" => 1454265000000, "y" => 94.918),
array("x" => 1456770600000, "y" => 95.152),
array("x" => 1459449000000, "y" => 97.070),
array("x" => 1462041000000, "y" => 97.305),
array("x" => 1464719400000, "y" => 89.854),
array("x" => 1467311400000, "y" => 88.158),
array("x" => 1469989800000, "y" => 87.989),
array("x" => 1472668200000, "y" => 86.366),
array("x" => 1475260200000, "y" => 81.650),
array("x" => 1477938600000, "y" => 85.789),
array("x" => 1480530600000, "y" => 83.846),
array("x" => 1483209000000, "y" => 84.927),
array("x" => 1485887400000, "y" => 82.609),
array("x" => 1488306600000, "y" => 81.428),
array("x" => 1490985000000, "y" => 83.259),
array("x" => 1493577000000, "y" => 83.153),
array("x" => 1496255400000, "y" => 84.180),
array("x" => 1498847400000, "y" => 84.840),
array("x" => 1501525800000, "y" => 82.671),
array("x" => 1504204200000, "y" => 87.496),
array("x" => 1506796200000, "y" => 86.007),
array("x" => 1509474600000, "y" => 87.233),
array("x" => 1512066600000, "y"=> 86.276)
```

And then further down in the JS section of the code, it formats this data with the following code:

```
xValueType: "dateTime",
xValueFormatString: "MMM YYYY",
```

So, my question is that how does those number in the x key in the array translate to months like in this attached image here?
[image: image of the chart in action]

And also, how would I convert my php datetime object to translate into those numbers in the x variable of the datapoints array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CanvasJS is a JavaScript library and accepts number / JavaScript date-object / JavaScript timestamp as x-value. As you have date object in PHP, first you should convert PHP datetime to PHP timestamp using [strtotime](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). Then you need to [convert it to JavaScript timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/847196/5808897) (multiplying PHP timestamp by 1000).

And according to [documentation](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/xvaluetype/), if you are providing timestamp values instead of Date objects, you’ll have to explicitly set the xValueType to "dateTime". So when you pass timestamp to the chart-options and set xValueType to "dateTime", library considers it as date-time.

**Note:** In PHP, timestamp is the value represented as seconds calculated, since UNIX Epoch, January 1, 1970 (also called as UNIX timestamp) - which you are calling as number.